# get a Spark Dataframe histogram after groupBy count

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large Spark DataFrame and after a groupBy-count operation, a summary of my dataset can be obtained as follow:

```
myResultDF

+---+---+-----+----------+
|SEX|AGE|count|    result|
+---+---+-----+----------+
|  1|  4| 1420| 0.2665724|
|  2|  8|  801|0.32442601|
|  1|  1| 2123| 0.2259348|
|  2|  3| 1329| 0.2732647|
|  2|  2| 1224|0.28158098|
|  1|  2| 1295|0.27588340|
|  2|  6| 1063| 0.2958312|
+---+---+-----+----------+
```

Now, I would like to generate a histogram of my results between 0 and 1, while taking into account the `count` column.

So far, following [this link](http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/statistical-data-exploration-spark-part-2/) I can create a histogram of my result without considering the `count` column:

```
val histogramX = (0 to 10 toArray).map({case (x: Int) => x.toDouble / 10})

val histogramY = myResultDF
      .select("result")
      .map(value => value.getDouble(0))
      .rdd.histogram(histogramX, true)
```

This code only gives me a histogram of six occurrences between 0.2 and 0.3, and one occurrence between 0.3 and 0.4.

But what I want is (1420+2123+1329+1224+1295+1063) occurrences between 0.2 and 0.3, and 801 occurences between 0.3 and 0.4.

Any suggestions for this calculation would be much appreciated :)

Comment: why don't you apply the histogram function before you apply count aggregation? that should give you the result you need.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.Forgot to mention. The result depends on the count and I prefer not to go back to the massive dataframe myResultDFderived from.

Comment: Also, I have to match and insert the result into the corresponding rows of the original dataframe for histogram counting. That could be more messy :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not use the rdd.histogram to solve my problem. As the values of my histogram is between 0 and 1, and the bins are evenly distributed in the order of 10's, I can simply truncate the *result* column via `(floor($"result" * histoBins) / histoBins)` and do a groupBy-count from the original dataframe.